# I run the following flutter dart code and nothing happen in android studio emulator

Tags: android, dart, flutter

This flutter app will check first time installation (for later use) and if it is first time, will go to login page. Unless, will check if it is already logged in. If it is already logged in, will go to FillBlankForm page. Unless, will go to Login page. I just want my app to login once and will always be logged in (even exit from app) until it is logged out (like facebook). Nothing happen when I run codes. Is anybody check and tell me what is going wrong with these codes. Thank you. 
This is main.dart.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:f_ppms/routes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Ariel',
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: routes,
    );
  }

}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
    SharedPreferences prefSeen = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _seen = (prefSeen.getBool('seen') ?? false);

    //if seen is true
    if (_seen) {
      print('seen already');

      //go to login screen
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'loginPage');
    } else {
      print('not seen yet');
      prefSeen.setBool('seen', true);
      print('just seen now');

      //login already?
      bool _isLogin = (prefSeen.getBool('isLogin') ?? false);

      //already login
      //go to home page
      if (_isLogin) {
        print('login already');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'fillBlankForm');
      }
      else{
        //not login yet
        //show login screen
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'loginPage');
        //if successfully login, set login data pref to Y
      }

    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('before super.initistate');
    super.initState();
    print('after super.initistate');
    checkFirstSeen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is routes.dart.

```
import 'fillBlankForm/fillBlankForm.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'noti.dart';

final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/': (context) => MyHomePage(),
  '/loginPage': (context) => LoginPage(),
  '/fillBlankForm': (context) => FillBlankForm(),
  '/noti': (context) => NotificationPage(),
};
```

Comment: Never return null. If you doesn't want to show any Widget, return something like Container().

Comment: Although I put return Container();, nothing happen. At least I think it should show some error or print something.